# Can Google Calendar load a custom Alternate Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar's settings, there's a drop-down labelled "Alternate calendar," with choices such as "Persian calendar" and "Hebrew calendar".

Is there a way to create and use a custom Alternate calendar?

I'm hoping I can write a script/program to generate a `.csv` file or something like that, and then somehow load that file into Google Calendar.  But I'm not sure what the format of that file would be, nor how to get it loaded in.

Comment: What would the use of that be?